# How can a Symfony web app itself detect unapplied Doctrine Migrations?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

The normal way of dealing with Doctrine Migrations is via the standard Commands - during development one runs the commands manually to e.g. run diffs and apply the migrations, and deployment typically involves applying them the by the same approach but automatically.  Occasionally when working in a team on a local instance there are new migrations, but I've updated my source from version control rather than done a deployment, so I need to apply the new migrations manually, and I need to know that I need to do that!  An improvement could be to display a warning on a rendered webpage that migrations are out of sync and action needs to be taken.

Is there a way to access the Migrations API directly in PHP/Symfony code, so that I could detect a mismatch between committed and applied migrations?  I haven't found any documentation about that.  I've had an initial poke around the code and it seems heavily skewed towards Commands (reasonably enough).

Comment: You can [invoke programmatically](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html) the "schema validate" command anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, updating your source code from version control, is a deployment too, and applying Doctrine Migrations should be part of that. You should create a check list of all the steps you need to do during a deployment, including rollbacks. Depending on the complexity of the application, many things could go wrong.

To answer you question, you can execute, in your code, a diff migration with the [Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) component and parse the output to determine if there're migrations to be applied.